# mariadb: replication master and slave have equal MySQL server ids

Tags: replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication, mariadb-10.4

I'm a novice mariadb user trying to set up a master with multiple slaves using mariadb-10.4.17 on fedora33.

I believe at one point I inadvertently ran the "change master" command on the actual master to be itself in addition to running it on the slaves. It appears that it was running properly for a while, but I've just noticed the following in the logs on the master:

```
2020-12-17  8:27:57 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-12-17  8:27:57 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-12-17  8:27:57 21 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master 'repuser@havoc.myserver.com:3306' in log 'mysql-bin.000674' at position 465296935
2020-12-17  8:27:59 21 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'repuser@havoc.myserver.com:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000674' at position 465296935
2020-12-17  8:27:59 21 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it). Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
```

The "mysql-bin.000674" file does not exist anywhere on the filesystem. I've now stopped the slave, but is there something else I should do?

None of the current slaves are using the same IDs and the server itself is not shown among the lists of slaves.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave hosts;
+-----------+-------------------------------+------+-----------+
| Server_id | Host                          | Port | Master_id |
+-----------+-------------------------------+------+-----------+
|        22 | armor.myserver.com            | 3306 |       590 |
|        11 | xavier.myserver.com           | 3306 |       590 |
|         2 | mail03.myserver.com           | 3306 |       590 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RESET SLAVE ALL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reset-slave-connection_name/) on the master to forget about is slave replication setting to itself.